# How to sort items in a table which are not numbers or text in React JS with Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using Material UI's enhanced table with React JS allowing the sorting of values (either ascending or descending). I have now added icons in some of the fields in the data and want to be able to assign a value to them to allow the sorting. For example: a tick icon being assigned the value 'true'.

I attempted to add a `{value}` field in the icons, but this did not work.

`<div color='secondary'><Done value={'false'}/></div>`

Where 'Done' is an material-ui imported icon.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @chornge just updated it now.

Comment: You are currently passing false as string. Did you wanted it to be boolean?

Comment: @LazarNikolic it doesnt matter what the specific value is, I just wanted to set it to something so that it is sortable as if it were text/number.